# Dialogflow - Fulfillment request pay load - How to register the user with user id received in request payload

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, skype-bots

What are the google/Microsoft(Skype) APIs available in order to register user in my application with the same user id as received in fulfillment request payload to my web hook?

I receive following for skype:

```
{  
   "originalDetectIntentRequest":{  
      "source":"skype",
      "payload":{  
         "user":{  
            "name":"Sana Zehra",
            "id":"29:1I3o3Np8sTLU7YSuhHO-IDuc1SgqMwg-83YwGryAZceE"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

For Google I receive this:

```
    {  
   "originalDetectIntentRequest":{  
      "payload":{  
         "user":{  
            "lastSeen":"2019-01-02T07:57:02Z",
            "locale":"en-US",
            "userId":"ABwppHHxPEyGWY1R26WqV3o5i1w8YNGbAIn5TXd28cre8Eu3iWtPlJEMuSzPWIW1b5u8e94djCv1xvmszegO1Q"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I need to register my users with this id as I authenticate if an incoming request is a registered user or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "register user in my application"? What information do you need besides the id?

Comment: @prisoner I need to store this Id against the actual google/Microsoft account

Comment: Wanted to ask what APIs are available so that when I sign up with Microsoft/google .. I get this Id

Answer (score 2):

You would need to build a flow for registration something that allows you to gather all the required information and register the user at your end, you can then verify if the user is registered by validating them against their id.

A sample article that handles the user registration via chatbot scenario:
https://medium.com/@sage.mcenery/building-a-registration-chatbot-on-aws-with-lex-and-twilio-4a14c15b8725

You can use google helpers in case of assistant which can give you the following additional info about the user:
Display name,
Given name,
Family name,
Coarse device location (zip code and city),
Precise device location (coordinates and street address)

Documentation on the same:
https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#built-in_helper_intents

I've never tried this myself though so I'm not too sure about this.

I do not think Skype and Google will give you much info about the user if that's what your looking for but a unique id against the user should do the trick in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Neither ID has any direct relation to the user's account on that platform.

Furthermore, the `userId` provided on the Actions on Google platform has been deprecated, and is [scheduled to be removed](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info) in May 2019.

The suggested way to associate the user's Google account with their session with you is to use [Google Sign In for Assistant](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in). With the user's one-time permission, you can then get their Google profile ID and other profile information.

Comment: what about Microsoft?